# What's the fastest way to draw sth on UIView?

Tags: swift, uiview, graphics, computer-vision, metal

I'm developing a msqrd-like game and I can see that SpriteKit is kinda slow, so is manual adding .addSubview. What's the other way to draw simple 2d object (so it'll really fast)?

Comment: Regards to SpriteKit - are you trying things on a real device (that has a GPU) or the simulator (which doesn't)? I'd think SK is optimized for using a GPU. Regards to drawing in UIKit - look into using CoreGraphics.

Comment: SpriteKit isn't slow. But if you want to code your game without SpriteKit then you can use Core Animation layers directly. I've done this for a Mahjong-type game and it works just as fast as anything else. For example, you can create "sprite sheets" and assign this image to multiple CA layers at the same time, and have each layer show only a small rectangle. Then add your animations using regular UIKit or Core Animation code.